# Dashboard.ly how to change the height and width of a row?

Tags: dashboard, plotly

I'm trying to create a dashboard like this http://help.plot.ly/dashboards.ly/#python-------------example
question is there is no option in json structure to change the size of each row, it seems that they are fixed.